# Как создать массив через указатель и отдельную функцию?

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

На вход подается длина массива и элементы массива. Нужно найти квадраты элементов массива. Ввод, возведение и вывод реализовать отдельными функциями при помощи указателей.

```
3
1 45 26
```

Обращаться к значениям массива нужно через адрес

```
int input(int *n, int data[]);
//void output(int *n, int *data);
//void squaring(int *n, int *data);

int main() {
    int n, data[n];
    input(&n, &data);
    //squaring(&n, &data);
    //output(&n, &data);
    return 0;
}

int input(int n, int data[]) {
    scanf("%d", n);
    for (int *pd=data[]; pd<data[n]; pd++){
        scanf("%d", *pd);
    }
       
//или так 

    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int *pd=data; pd<(pd+n); pd++) {
        scanf("%d", *pd);
    }

}
```

Конечно нужно отдельной во второй функции реализовать возведение в квадрат.
а третьей вывести
Будет здорово если поможете разобраться хотябы с первой

Comment: В чем сверхзадача? Зачем что-то куда-то передавать, если неизвестно, что с этим делать? :)

Comment: Поправил задачу

Answer (score 1):

Ну, что-то типа (если не прибегать к не везде реализованному VLA)

```
void input(int* data, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) scanf("%d",data+i);
}

void calc(int* data, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) *(data+i) *= *(data+i);
}

void output(int* data, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) printf("%d ",*(data+i));
    puts("");
}


int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int * data = malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    input(data, n);
    calc(data,n);
    output(data,n);

    free(data);
}
```

P.S. Вводил прямо тут, не компилируя (это если где-то выпрыгнут очепятки).

Поскольку написанный вариант кажется ТС недостаточно через указатели, вот еще один. Если опять не понравится — устрою ему трехзвездочную жизнь...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
void input(int* data, int n)
{
    for(int * end = data + n; data < end; ++data) scanf("%d",data);
}
 
void calc(int* data, int n)
{
    for(int * end = data + n; data < end; ++data) *data *= *data;
}
 
void output(int* data, int n)
{
    for(int * end = data + n; data < end; ++data) printf("%d ",*data);
    puts("");
}
 
 
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int * data = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
 
    input(data, n);
    calc(data,n);
    output(data,n);
 
    free(data);
}
```

Решение, в котором нет ничего, кроме указателей:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
void input(int** data, int** n)
{
    for(int *p = *data, * end = p + **n; p < end; ++p) scanf("%d",p);
}
 
void calc(int** data, int **n)
{
    for(int *p = *data, * end = p + **n; p < end; ++p) *p *= *p;
}
 
void output(int** data, int **n)
{
    for(int *p = *data, * end = p + **n; p < end; ++p) printf("%d ",*p);
    puts("");
}
 
 
int main()
{
    int * n = malloc(sizeof(int));
    scanf("%d",n);
    int * data = malloc((*n)*sizeof(int));
 
    input (&data,&n);
    calc  (&data,&n);
    output(&data,&n);
 
    free(data);
    free(n);
}
```

Comment: scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int *pd=data; pd<(pd+n); pd++) {
        scanf("%d", *pd);
    }
а такой подобный код имеет право на жизнь?

Comment: Написать-то можно всё... Только сами скажите мне, когда цикл остановится? Ну, т.е. когда прекратит выполняться условие `pd<(pd+n)`?

Comment: int input(int *n, int data[]) {
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int *pd=data; pd<(data+n); pd++) {
        scanf("%d", pd);
    }
}

Comment: Ну, это дело другое...

Comment: но не компилит error: invalid operands to binary + (have 'int *' and 'int *')
   18 |     for (int *pd=data; pd<(data+n); pd++) {
      |

Comment: Вот, так устроит? https://ideone.com/OU5ief Ковыряться, что именно вы делаете, по какому-то отрывку из обрывка — не хочется. Не нравится мое решение — никто не неволит, пишите и отлаживайте свое. Скорее всего, у вас что-то не то с объявлениями переменных. По сообщению компилятора у вас `n` — указатель...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137052/discussion-between-el-muerto-de-mederti-and-harry).

Comment: Зачем вы вообще делаете `n` указателем?!

Comment: я не знаю я уже запутался. мне просто нужно корректно передать кол-во элементов и сам массив в функцию. а цикл обработать через инкремент указателя! примерно for(int *p = a; /*условие проверки*/ ; p++)

Comment: ответ на C++ сойдёт или вам C принципиально надо?

Comment: Я написал, как это сделать. Двумя разными способами. Что именно в ответе вам непонятно?

Comment: Теперь уже тремя — смотрите ответ...

Comment: Спасибо, трехзвездоочную пока не надо 